# jQuery autocomplete - adding to underlying local datasource array

Tags: jquery

In this basic example using jQuery autocomplete:

```
$("#textboxid").autocomplete(
    {
        source: testdata,
        delay: 100,
        minLength: 1
    });
```

where `testdata` is a local array of data, what is the recommended way to have any changes to the underlying source array, reflect in the autocomplete options?

Currently, if I subsequently add a new item to the `testdata` array (i.e. after the autocomplete has already been setup on the textbox element), I don't see that new option in the autocomplete list. If I dynamically add a new textbox to the page and set up for autocomplete, it does see the new option. But existing elements do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible way is to use a callback as the source, which polls your array/object/server for the data and returns the appropriate response.

Here is an example of how you could test this:

```
var testdata = ["foo","bar","baz","quux"];
$("#textboxid").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, callback) {
        var possiblematches = testdata.filter(function(v) {
            return v.match($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term));
        });
        callback(possiblematches);
    },
    delay: 100
});
```

A demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Eeg5L/. Documentation and further information for the `source` option can be found [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

Alternatively, you could reset the source after modifying the array using:

```
$("#textboxid").autocomplete("option","source", testdata);
```

I'd recommend using a setter for your array that does this automatically whenever you modify the array.

Comment: Thanks - works nicely. Decided this route was the best all round, instead of "reapplying" the autocomplete each time.

Answer (score 0):

When you update `testdata` run this :

```
$('#textboxid').autocomplete('option', 'source', testdata);
```